# Correctly convert price into a 8 digits string on ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to convert a price into a string of 8 digits and right now, I'm using this:

```
=Format(Replace(Round([total],2),",",""),"00000000")
```

If the price is (eg: 105.55) it converts like this: `00010455` and this is ok!

**The problem:**

When the price ends with a zero (like this: 147.60). In this case, it returns `00001476`and it's missing the last zero which I need to correctly solve the rest.

Even if I remove the `Round` part, I get the same problem.

```
=Format(Replace([total],",",""),"00000000")
```

I can't figure why this is happening and how to do it right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simpler approach:

```
=Format([total] * 100, "00000000")
```